# Htaccess to show different root for different ip's

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond ${ipmap:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} ^allow$            [NC]

RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

I would like to know if it's possible to redirect the IP's from the list to another folder but they still see the same URL (`example.com`) and not `example.com/folder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 

# Rewrite requests to "/folder" for specific IPs
RewriteCond ${ipmap:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} ^allow$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^folder/ folder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

You shouldn't need the `NC` on the rule that matches from your rewrite map. (Assuming your *map* is consistently using `allow` and not any other mixed case version of this?)

If everything is to be rewritten to `/folder` and you aren't referencing any static resources outside of `/folder` then you can perhaps remove the two *conditions* that perform the filesystem checks (to test whether the request does not already map to a file or directory).

---

As an added bonus, you can prevent direct user access to the `/folder` and redirect back to the root with something like the following *before* the above rewrite (immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive):

```
# Redirect direct requests to "/folder" back to root
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^folder(?:$|/(.*)) /$1 [R=301,L]
```

(NB: This does assume you don't have another `.htaccess` file in the `/folder` subdirectory that contains mod_rewrite directives. If you do then you would need to preform this redirect in *that* `.htaccess` file instead.)